# Match sequence of characters in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match a sequence of letters in a string. For instance if I have the letters T B E I want to match all strings that starts with the letter T and contains the letters B and E at least once. The second letter has to appear before the third, and there might be an infinite number of characters between the letters.

That is the letters T B E would match the strings
Table, Trouble and Terrible but not Teb.

I'm trying to code this in php by using

```
$A = 'T';
$B = 'B';
$C = 'E';

$matches = preg_grep('/^'.$A.'.+'.$B.'.+'.$C.'/', $words);
```

where words is an array containing a list of words. With my way the algorithm works, but I'm not able to  find words where there are no letters in between $A $B or $C.

How would I use regular expressions to fix this?

Comment: `Terrible` should not match then. *e occurs before b*

Comment: Well I want Terrible to match in that case. The important thing is that e comes at least once after b. It doesn't matter if it occurs before or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not able to find words where there are no letters in between $A $B or $C is because you are using `.+` which is trying to match atleast 1 character between $A $B or $C.

Use `.*` instead of `.+`

Comment: You should also make the regex case insensitive to match words like Table (`/^T[^E]*B.*E$/i`)